# requiring files inside electron / express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, express, electron

I am having some problems setting up an app using:

- electron
- express (with mustache templating)
- firebase

**I am having trouble finding the correct way to require files. I think the problem is that sometimes the "scope" is the electron app, sometimes the express app, and the paths don't resolve correctly.**

My file structure looks like this:

```
app
  |- app.js (here i start the electron window)
  |- src
     |- js
       |- app-server.js (my express server)
       |- firebase.js (here i initialize firebase)
       |- login.js (here i want to write the js for the login view)
     |- styles
       |- app.css
     |- views
       |- login.html
```

my app.js (where i start and configure electron) looks like this:

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const server = require('./src/js/app-server');

let mainWindow;

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1200,
    height: 800,
    resizable: false,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadURL('http://localhost:3000')
}

app.whenReady().then(createWindow)
```

My app-server.js looks like this:

```js
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const mustacheExpress = require('mustache-express');
const firebase = require('./firebase');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.engine('html', mustacheExpress());

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views',  path.join(__dirname, '/../views'));
app.use('/viewsStyles', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/../styles')));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('login', {});
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`These console logs come on the TERMINAL`);
})
```

My firebase.js (where i initialize my firebase app) looks like this:

```js
const firebase = require('firebase');

const firebaseConfig = {
  // my firebase config
};

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


module.exports = firebase;
```

When i start up the app, everything looks ok.
But then i need to add a click event listener on the login button (on the login view). For this i have created the `src/js/login.js` file, which i import inside the `src/views/login.html`.

But here when i try to require the firebase object that i am exporting on the `/firebase.js` i get a:
`cannot find module './firebase'`. (inside the app-server.js i can require it without problems)

If i console log the `__dirname`on the login.js file i get:
`/pathToMyAppFolder/my-app/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/electron.asar/renderer`

How can i organize my files, so that i can used them where i need them?

Do you have any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you try this: **const firebase = require('firebase/app');** and **const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);** with **module.export = app**

Comment: @RadekDeveloper do you mean in the firebase.js? Tried now, but no change. I think the firebase.js is initializing the app correctly, my problem is then requiring the initialized firebase object in other files...

Answer (score 0):

I am trying the same thing with nedb/vue/express/electron...
when i try to resolve __dirPath in my web app(vue) its actually showing the asar structure.

The way i solved this is i made endpoints in my express for the vue app to talk to and in express i am saving the data. hope that gives you some ideas.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I ended up starting the whole project from scratch and i didn't use firebase anymore.  :/   in the new project i had a similar problem and i solved it using the alias plugin during the rollup build...